# df.apply(lambda: x.lower()): 'function' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, dataframe, stringtokenizer

I have written this code in Jupyter, but I get an error message:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer (r'\w+')

career_df['How could the conversation have been more useful?']= career_df['How could the conversation have been more useful?'].apply(lambda x:tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower()))
```

The error is

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: You should [edit] your question to indicate which libraries you `import` so we don't have to guess. Ideally, the code should constitute a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your "x" in lambda Expression is acting as a function when it should be a string.
Try :

```
  career_df['How could the conversation have been more useful?']= career_df.apply(lambda x:tokenizer.tokenize(x['How could the conversation have been more useful?'].lower()))
```